# Как получить список приложений эквивалентный меню Открыть с помощью

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как на С++ получить список установленных в Windows приложений, аналогичных тому, что появляется при нажатии в контекстном меню мыши "Открыть с помощью..." в виде:
<иконка или путь к иконке>, <путь к .exe файлу приложения>, <Человекочитаемое название приложения>?
Программирую в Qt Creator.

Comment: Вам нужен именно список установленных приложений вообще или список ассоциированных (который появляется в Открыть с помощью)?

Answer (score 5):

Диалог "Открыть с помощью" отображает не список всех установленных приложений, он составляет список приложений на основе двух источников:

1. Приложения, перечисленные в ключе реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications`, для которых не определен параметр NoOpenWith.
2. Приложения, зарегистрированные для конкретного расширения файлов в следующих ключах:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.(расширение)\OpenWithProgids
HKCU\Software\Classes\.(расширение)\OpenWithProgids
HKCU\Software\Classes\.(расширение)\OpenWithList
```

Чтобы перейти от имени exe-файла к его полному пути, нужно найти его в одной из следующих веток:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\
```

Далее, значок приложения и его читаемое описание обычно нигде в реестре явно не прописаны и берутся из ресурсов EXE-файла.

Для получения значка можно использовать функцию [ExtractIcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonw)

Для получения описания можно использовать функцию [VerQueryValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew), передавая в качестве пути к ресурсу строку вида `\StringFileInfo\lang-codepage\FileDescription`.

Для примера, вывод списка программ из `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383

void QueryKey(HKEY hKey) 
{ 
    wchar_t    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
    wchar_t    achClass[MAX_PATH] = L"";  // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys=0;               // number of subkeys 
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

    DWORD type;
    DWORD cdata; 
    HKEY hSubkey;
    DWORD i, retCode; 

    wchar_t  achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME]; 
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 

    // Get the class name and the value count. 
    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

    // Enumerate the subkeys

    if (cSubKeys == 0) {
        wprintf(L"Error: no subkeys!\n",achKey);        
    }
    else {        

        for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
        { 
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,
                     achKey, 
                     &cbName, 
                     NULL, 
                     NULL, 
                     NULL, 
                     &ftLastWriteTime); 
            if (retCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) continue;                           

            retCode =   RegOpenKey(hKey,achKey,&hSubkey);

            if(retCode != ERROR_SUCCESS){
                    wprintf(L"%s: RegOpenKey failed\n",achKey);
                    continue;
            }

            retCode = RegQueryValueEx(hSubkey,L"NoOpenWith",NULL,&type,NULL,&cdata);
            if(retCode == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){                    
                    wprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), achKey);
            }
            RegCloseKey(hSubkey);            
        }
    }     
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    HKEY hTestKey;

   if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
        L"Applications",
        0,
        KEY_READ,
        &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS
      )
   {
      QueryKey(hTestKey);
   }

   RegCloseKey(hTestKey);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Источники:

[Application registration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration#using-the-applications-subkey)

[Enumerating registry subkeys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/enumerating-registry-subkeys)

[How to Exclude an Application from the Open With Dialog Box for Unassociated File Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-exclude-an-application-from-the-open-with-dialog-box-for-unassociated-file-types)

Comment: Там, похоже, немного запутанней все. Например, я вижу немало приложений, у которых `NoOpenWith` не задан, но в диалоге `Open With` они тем не менее отсутствуют. Да и вообще список в `Open With` намного меньше, чем список в `HKCR\Applications`.

Comment: @freim В Windows 10 похоже сделано так, что отображаются все зарегистрированные для данного расширения + не более 10 приложений из `HKCR\Applications`.